# how to get secret key(access token) in React app from another UI app for SSO

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

We have two web application let's say *http://app1.com* and *http://app2.com* hosted on the different domain.

App1-> communicate to OAuth server to get the access token, which we store in browser's local storage.

App2 -> simple frontend app developed in React.

Now we want to navigate to app2 from app1 with the help of an existing token. Which will be then used to call the APIs from app2.

*Problem:* As we can't access local storage from a different domain. so we have to get the access token again after redirected to the new application.

*Current approach:*
We are passing encrypted username from app1 while redirecting. Then we make a call to Oauth server with that username to get access Token.

I am sure there will be a better way to achieve this. Any reference pointer will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass anything from pp1 to app2. Just use standard OpenID connect flow in app2 (implicit one for React). App2 will redirect user to used Identity Provider (IdP), where user has already opened session, so IdP will redirect browser back to the app2 with own access token for app2.